# Human manual error in SecureCRT, what are the ways to automate?

Tags: python-3.x, paramiko, netmiko, juniper, secure-crt

We had an error in the Multicast forwarding table when my colleague was working in SecureCRT, he deleted the IP and all that was left was "then"(block....) and we took down our entire network. I want it to be automated and reduce human error. Which use and why?
we use juniper devices.

I found several ways, for example: paramiko, netmiko.

how can I create safly ways and what use I will?
what I found SecureCRT is not safely in this cases.